# Behaviour of a Future in an IO Monad

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have written a function that returns an IO value:

```
def foo(x : Int): IO[Future[Int]] = IO {
  // do some IO
  }
```

I am using the IO typeclass from Scalaz.

I then use this in for expression as follows:

```
  (for {
    _ <- foo(10)
  } yield bar()).unsafePerformIO()
```

Since the result of calling `foo` is a `Future` will this `Future` execute in a separate thread and the `yield`, will instantaneously call `bar()`, or will the yield wait until the `Future` has completed before calling `bar()`?

Update:

I ran the following experiment and it looks like it does not yield instantaneously:

```
def foo() : IO[Future[Unit]] = IO { Future.successful(bar()) }

def bar() : Unit = {
  Thread.sleep(200000);
  println("done")
}

scala> (for {
     | _ <- foo()
     | } yield "bar").unsafePerformIO()
res3: String = bar
```

Is there a way to asynchronously process that future?

Comment: Try running your tests with small modification: instead of `IO { Future.successful(bar()) }` run `IO { Future(bar()) }`. From source code I understood that `Future.successful(fun())` simply wraps `fun()` call in either `Success` or `Failure` (via dedicated `Promise` methods). It does NOT use ExecutionContext and as a result it does NOT run in a separate thread. If you use `def foo() : IO[Future[Int]] = IO { Future.successful(bar()) }` and then run `bar()` I would expect it to yield immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IO { Future.successful(bar()) }
```

will execute `bar()`, wrap it with `Success` or `Failure` and put result in `IO`.

On the other hand

```
IO { Future { bar() } } // or IO { Future(bar()) }
```

will delegate `bar()` execution into separate thread via implicit `ExecutorContext`.

`Future(value: => T)` is an asynchronous call and what you are looking for, while `Future.successful(value: => T)` is synchronous and should be used only for immediate return of already calculated values.